# How to set Navigation menu based on User type - SOCIALENGINE

Tags: zend-framework, menu, authorization, socialengine

How to set Navigation based on user type/profile type logged in.

All I could do is - set auth for specific user type

```
if (!$this->_helper->requireAuth()->setAuthParams('<module>', null, 'create')->isValid())
        return;
```

But with this the menu will be still available 
For example - If a Candidate logs in I should be able to hide create JOB menu.

Please give some insights on this. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a function in menu.php in plugin of your module.You can check user module and also add a entry 'engine4_core_menuitems'. In table find your menu add entry in plugin _Plugin_Menus. Below function will have naming convention as your your function Name.

```
  public function onMenuInitialize_JobMenu()
{
     $viewer = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer();

      //assuming level id 4 for candidate
if( !$viewer->level_id == '4') {
  return false;
}

return array(
  'label' => 'create Job',
  'route' => 'job_general',
  'params' => array(
    'action' => 'groupsms'
)
);
```

}